# Pagination issue with Haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack, django-pagination

I am using alphabetical pagination with haystack that I borrowed from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1364/

But named pagination is hitting the database which it shouldn't. Line 15 is causing this, although I have same iteration code in a django template that that works fine.

UPDATED:

search_view.py

```
import json
from django.core import serializers

from django.core.paginator import InvalidPage, Paginator
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render_to_response

from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import FacetedSearchView

from directory.named_paginator import NamedPaginator


class FacetedSearchCustomView(FacetedSearchView):
"""
Overrides various default methods to allow for additional context, smoother UX for faceting
"""

def build_page(self):
    """
    Paginates the results appropriately.

    Overriden to redirect to page 1 if a page_no is not found
    """
    try:
        page_no = int(self.request.GET.get('page', 1))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise Http404("Not a valid number for page.")

    if page_no < 1:
        raise Http404("Pages should be 1 or greater.")

    paginator = NamedPaginator(self.results, on="brand", per_page=self.results_per_page)
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_no)
    except InvalidPage:
        # Redirect to page 1 of the
        path = self.request.path
        qs = self.request.GET.copy()
        qs['page'] = 1
        url = '%s?%s' % (path, qs.urlencode())
        return redirect(url)

    return paginator, page

def clean_filters(self):
    """Returns a list of tuples (filter, value) of applied facets"""
    filters = []
    # get distinct facets
    facets = list(set(self.form.selected_facets))
    for facet in facets:
        if ":" not in facet:
            continue
        field, value = facet.split(":", 1)
        field = field.replace('_', ' ').replace('exact', '').title()
        filters.append((field, value))
    return filters

def create_response(self):
    """
    Generates the actual HttpResponse to send back to the user.

    Overriding to allow the redirect to pass through from overriden build_page
    """
    try:
        (paginator, page) = self.build_page()
    except ValueError:
        return self.build_page()

    context = {
        'query': self.query,
        'form': self.form,
        'page': page,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'suggestion': None,
    }

    if self.results and hasattr(self.results, 'query') and self.results.query.backend.include_spelling:
        context['suggestion'] = self.form.get_suggestion()

    context.update(self.extra_context())
    return render_to_response(self.template, context, context_instance=self.context_class(self.request))

def extra_context(self):
    extra = super(FacetedSearchCustomView, self).extra_context()
    extra['filters'] = self.clean_filters()
    if not self.results:
        extra['facets'] = self.form.search().facet_counts()
    else:
        extra['facets'] = self.results.facet_counts()

    model_type = self.request.path.split('/')[1].rstrip('s')
    extra['model_type'] = None if model_type == "search" else model_type
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATED:

```
{  
    "store":{  
        "mappings":{  
            "modelresult":{  
                "_boost":{  
                    "name":"boost",
                    "null_value":1
                },
                "properties":{  
                    "brand":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"synonym_analyzer"
                    },
                    "brand_auto":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"edgengram_analyzer"
                    },
                    "brand_slug":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"synonym_analyzer"
                    },
                    "brand_sort":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"synonym_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you pass the SearchQuerySet and not model's queryset to the Paginator. It would be better if you shared your code.

Comment: @AnimeshSharma updated with search view code, named_paginator.py is exactly the same as in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with the indexing. You are trying to perform the pagination on the field `"brand"` and it is most likely that this field is not indexed in Solr/Elastic search.

Solr performs a DB query only for the fields which are not indexed.

Hope this sorts out the issue.

Comment: Brand is indexed, added the mapping. Also I am accessing the brand property in the django template and it still works.

Comment: Try putting this in build_page before calling the paginator.
`start_offset = (page_no - 1) * self.results_per_page`           
   
`self.results[start_offset:start_offset + self.results_per_page]`

Comment: Added those two lines before creating an instance of NamedPaginator and still hitting the database.

Comment: Beats me. Do post the solution when you find it.